# Does Response.Redirect affect google analytics?

Tags: .net, redirect, google-analytics

We'd like to create a simple 'friendly url' on a site that Response.Redirects to the actual ugly url. Will this impact Google analytics at all?

example: /somepage redirects to /index.aspx?someuglyquerystring

Thanks.

**Edit**

And further to that, I'm assuming that Server.Transfer would be ok here? I did run into a gotcha in trying this - because I'm redirecting to a page that uses a master page, I had to change all of the ~ based links to absolute links, otherwise I got the nice and cryptic:

> Cannot use a leading .. to exit above
>   the top directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Response.Redirect issues a 302 response code to the browser, specifically this header:

```
HTTP 1.0 302 Object Moved 
Location  
http://<new url>
```

Google Analytics will recognize this and report the original URL as the "referring URL" to the new page. [This Google Analytics forum post may help clear it up](http://www.dannytalk.com/2009/03/15/google-analytics-does-301302-redirect-preserve-referrer-information/).

As far as my understanding goes, there are no penalties for your search ranking when using proper redirection techniques.

Comment: So if I want to maintain the original referrer (in my example, /somepage) then I need to do a 301 redirect to the actual ugly url? Or, will that not preserve the referrer either?

Comment: Sorry my post is probably unclear.  If some external site links to /somepage (which then 302's to /uglypage), google analytics will still track the external site as the referrer.  /somepage is not counted as the referrer.